# How to pass data to destination with multiple back stack approach in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

In a project im using multiple back stack feature with bottom navigation tabs. Everything is working fine with first enter to destination - with deeplink, user interaction - tab click or by navigating programatically. Im using [2.5.2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.5.2) version. BottomNavigationView is set up with [setupWithNavController()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#setupWithNavController(com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView,androidx.navigation.NavController))

Assume we have A, B, C back stacks (root fragments/root destinations) available in bottom navigation.
Steps to reproduce (in [?] are bottom navigation btns):

```
    1. Click [B] tab - [B] becomes visible.
    '''''''''''
    '         '
    '    B    '
    '         '
    '         '
    ''''''''''' 
    [A] [B] [C]
    2. Click [C] tab - [C] visible.
    '''''''''''
    '         '
    '    C    '
    '  (BNT)  '
    '         '
    '''''''''''
    [A] [B] [C]
    3. In [C] click (BNT) button, which moves [C]->[B] with additional information. [B] is visible, information is not passed.
    '''''''''''
    '         '
    '    B    '
    '         '
    '         '
    '''''''''''
    [A] [B] [C]
```

Action in step 3 is defined like this (I tried it as global and local actions):

```xml
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_C_to_B"
    app:destination="@id/graph_B"
    app:restoreState="true"
    app:popUpTo="@id/destination_A"
    app:popUpToSaveState="true">

    <argument
        android:name="informationInt"
        app:nullable="false"
        app:argType="integer" />
</action>
```

What does not work?
Arguments passed in action are never available in destination B if we are entering it more then one time. I need InformationInt after (BTN) to be passed somehow to destination [B].

What I know:

1. Arguments are "immutable". They are set once destination is entered and restored on each reenter. It is because `app:restoreState="true"` flag is set - and it is ok - I want multiple back stack feature to remember its back stacks states.
2. A cannot set arguments one more time because of this:

```kotlin
/**
     * Supply the construction arguments for this fragment.
     * The arguments supplied here will be retained across fragment destroy and
     * creation.
     * <p>This method cannot be called if the fragment is added to a FragmentManager and
     * if {@link #isStateSaved()} would return true.</p>
     */
    public void setArguments(@Nullable Bundle args) {
        if (mFragmentManager != null && isStateSaved()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment already added and state has been saved");
        }
        mArguments = args;
    }
```

3. Using OnDestinationChangeListener does not help. It always returns arguments that where used while we first entered destination.

What im looking for?
I want to pass information to destination while reentering it in multiple back stack architecture. Each back stack must remember its state.

Comment: What is A,B,C? Are they fragments, activities, something else?

Comment: 'Assume we have A, B, C back stacks (root fragments/root destinations) available in bottom navigation' - what dont u understand? I will improve description.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to take some information with you when you go back and I will give my answer accordingly.
Suppose we have a fragment b and c and when we click back on c we will pass data to b

For this we write in c fragment

```
    navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(
                        "data-key",
                        data
                    )
```

and we getting data in b fragment

```
        navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<String>("data-key")
        ?.observeOnce(
            viewLifecycleOwner
        ) { result ->
             //Write code here
            }
        }
```

Comment: U cannot go back in multiple back stacks approach when navigating between root destinations/fragments. I will try to use savedStateHandle and get back with result.

Comment: It does not work. Moreover im not sure it will work event in the same back stack. There are 2 entries wen u navigate from one destination (1st) to another (2nd) and when u go back u change entry - I suppose.